# Collections list and dictionary

Tags: c#, list, collections, dictionary

I have a list that contains roleids and a dictionary that has database of roleids and menus accessible to that roleid.

Suppose a user has role `1,2,3` then how do I retrieve the distinct menus he can access from a dictionary?

```
List<int> roleids = new List<int>();

roleids.Add(1);
roleids.Add(2);
roleids.Add(3);

Dictionary<int, List<String>> Links = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
{
    { 1, new List<String> { "Home", "About Us", "Logout", "Help" } },
    { 2, new List<String> { "Home", "Products", "Logout", "Help" } },
    { 3, new List<String> { "Home", "Customers", "Users", "Help" } }
};
```

I want to create a new list that contains menus accessible to user based on values in List roleids

Answer (score 7):

If you do your initial select across the `roleids` list - you can leverage the fast-lookup nature of the dictionary

```
var menuItems = roleids
    .Select(id => Links[id])
    .SelectMany(roles => roles)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: @Dave Bish can you pls explain how SelectMany(roles=>roles) works.I mean roles is refering to which collection

Comment: After the first select, you end-up with a collection of lists (from the dictionary). SelectMany flattens all those lists, into one big list (with duplicates) - which are then removed by the Distinct()

Comment: but what does roles=>roles or any variable v=>v means in linq..Sorry if the question is annoying but i am new to all this

Comment: @DaveBish Can you also answer my previous question that I had posted " unable to write Linq query "

Comment: @user2381733 you've not accepted this one, as an answer, yet!

Comment: @DaveBish I am not saying about this question...but the link i gave above .I have accepted your answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var distinct = Links
    .Where(i => roleids.Contains(i.Key))
    .SelectMany(i => i.Value).Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This way avoids the fast-lookup of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve at first Links **where** role id in user's roleids, then **select** from this subset the values and avoid duplicates with **distinct**:

```
   var menus = Links.Where(l => roleids.Contains(l.key))
                     .SelectMany(k => k.Value)
                     .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this algorithm

```cs
public static List<string> GetMenuItems(List<int> userRoles)
    {
        var roleids = new List<int>();
        roleids.Add(1);
        roleids.Add(2);
        roleids.Add(3);
        var Links = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()
        {
             {1,new List<String> {"Home","About Us","Logout","Help"}},
             {2,new List<String>{"Home","Products","Logout","Help"}},
             {3,new List<String>{"Home","Customers","Users","Help"}}
        };
        var roleLinks = Links
            .Where(item => userRoles.Contains(item.Key))
            .SelectMany(item => item.Value)
            .ToList()
            .Distinct();
    }
```